# Remove box-shadow from Angular Material <mat-chip>

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, box-shadow

Is there any way to remove the box-shadow from [mat-chips in Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview)?

```
<mat-chip-list>
    <mat-chip>Papadum</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

The chips appear to have a CSS style for the box-shadow, but disabling this style or overriding it doesn't work.

```
transition: box-shadow 280ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
```

I suspect there must be a simple way to disable this shadow, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: use viewEncapsulation.none. If mat-chips has inline style, you can use !important in your css

Comment: Using !important in my css did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To all new readers coming to read this post. Apply this class in your 'mat-chip' element to remove z index. This will remove shadow also.

```html
class="mat-elevation-z0"
```

Comment: BTW, works for `mat-button` and presumably all such mat- controls too.

Answer (score 28):

Adding the following CSS with !important did the trick:

```
mat-chip {
    transition: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

No need for '!importants' this way

```css
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

mat-chip {
    @include mat-elevation(0);
}
```

Comment: this is great way what about mat-fab since it is added to button

Comment: @DživoJelić do something like this `.mat-fab:not([class*=mat-elevation-z]), .mat-mini-fab:not([class*=mat-elevation-z]) {
     box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px -1px rgb(0 0 0 /0%), 0px 6px 10px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 0%), 0px 1px 18px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 0%);
}`

Answer (score 2):

Overriding styles didn't help me. I have used mat-basic-chip instead.

Docs says: "For a chip with no styles applied, use `<mat-basic-chip>`. You can then customize the chip appearance by adding your own CSS."